# What is a yes/no question that forces the answerer to always lie?

Tags: logical-deduction

Can I ask a yes/no question so that no matter whether the answerer answers yes or no, he always lies?

Comment: Is lying the same as being wrong?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I guess I'd leave that ambiguous :)

Comment: I can't believe you guys missed the obvious, and the only correct answer: "Does this dress make me look fat?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A pretty simple one would be

> Is your answer to this question going to be "no"?

Comment: If I answer "That question results in a paradox.", then I haven't lied.

Comment: True, but then you aren't answering 'yes' or 'no', as the question requires.

Answer (score 4):

How about a question with a false premise?

> Have you stopped beating your wife? Asked of someone who has never beaten his wife.

Whether yes or no, the answer will not be true.

A slightly less sexist or upsetting version might be

> Did you make the hat you're wearing? Asked of someone who is not wearing a hat

Again if you can confine them to yes/no you can guarantee a lie

Or you can take a question that can only be answered "yes" or "no" and conflate it with the opposite

> Will you your answer to "are you asleep" be the same as this one?

Answer (score 0):

> "You didn't go to work today, right?"

You could possibly trap them with how you interpret it. So if I were to answer "no" You could respond with, "Oh, you didn't go to work!" when I was implying "no" to you being "right" or correct. 
Or if I answer no as in "I didn't go" you could respond "I could have sworn you weren't there!" as implying I was answering "no" to you being correct.

With "yes" I could mean "Yes, I did go to work" but you can take it as "Yes, I didn't go to work".
Or if I answered "yes" as in "Yes I didn't go" you can interpret it as "Yes, I didn't go"

I *think* this all makes sense and I think I covered the possibilities of just Yes or No being a possible answer.